# How to secure JSON calls of a HTML5 App to a Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security, authentication

I'm currently planning to develop a HTML5 app. The basic concept is the following:

A user should be able to create a profile with username and password. The Server should be implemented in Ruby on Rails providing a JSONP Api (for Cross-Domain issues).

So the App will send Ajax requests to the Server and get responses from it.

My idea was now to transmit a session_key (generated by server) on the first response back to the client. Then the client has to authenticate himself with this token.

But now i have some issues.

- How can i secure the first call of the client (when he is transmitting user and password)?
- How can i protect the Session-key from beeing spyed out?

I am a complety noob in security aspects. Therefore it would be great if i could get some hints where to look at.

Comment: Use SSL and that should help with spying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secure your connection with SSL. This should require no changes in your code apart from putting 's' after 'http' ;-).

Answer (score -2):

I used add a checksum to the ajax parameters (calculated using the submitted data), and then to crypt the hole ajax request into one string.

Somthing like sRequest=459fdjnfdw4r908vn....

sRequests holds my data (sUser=user&sPass=pass&iCheck=34564).

Edit: My client code was not public, compiled to an app.

Comment: Which encryption algorithm are you using?

Comment: this doesn't even have to suffer a MITM attack, just a sniffer can encrypt/decrypt the whole data in a few minutes analyzing the code

Comment: @pocesar, I doubt that you can encrypt a good encrpytion that easy, especially if you have your own encryption algorithim.

Comment: it's plain text, nothing in plain is hard to decrypt, and Javascript files being just *plain text*, two times easier, it doesn't matter if you created the encryption or you are using a ready solution. just a matter of analyzing the encryption/decryption routine (which defeats the purpose of encryption)

Comment: @Ilyssis - `own encryption algorithm` is one of the biggest security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Well, if your code is visible to the public then this is nothing, I agree.